3d viewport display rendering problem
I have this strange issue this morning... all objects seem to be half xrayish... last night all was good... as i pan or rotate is all flickers

Your Clip End (see in the top right of the 3D Viewport) is ridiculously high at 1111111125 m. Read more about it in the manual here: Depth Buffer Glitches or in one of the many answers on this topic on this site, for example: Glitchy Shadow effect, Why is my viewport glitching in orthographic view and not in perspective view

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

nope....
doesnt matter what values i put in.... also switching to Local view, everything disappears and trying to go back doesnt work either.... have to reopen the file to get back to here.... last night it was all good...

The values make no difference to this. Local view swapping also shows everything for a split second then the screen goes grey apart from the 3d cursor..... how do I post the file?
